# Laravel 5.8.17 - validation image not working as expected

Tags: laravel, forms, validation, laravel-5, input

I'm creating Laravel validation, and meet strange issue.

I have a form with input type file, where I can attach multiple files.

```
<input type="file" name="img[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
```

In the Controller I have validation rules:

```
$validationRules = [
   'img' => 'required|image'
];
```

And all the time my validation doesn't work, I always get a message:
**"The img must be an image."**

There is no difference when I upload 1 file or 2 or 3 at the same time - error is the same. There are another fields at the same form (text fields) and all is ok with them, problem appears only with image. Tried to remove **"image"**
 from the validation and replace it with **mimetypes** or **mimes** - anyway system can't recognize image.

Please advice what could be a problem here, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make validation attribute `img` to `img.*`

Answer (score 1):

```
   $input_data = $request->all();

   $validator = Validator::make(
        $input_data, [
        'img.*' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,bmp|max:20000'
        ],[
            'img.*.required' => 'Please upload an image',
            'img.*.mimes' => 'Only jpeg,png and bmp images are allowed',
            'img.*.max' => 'Sorry! Maximum allowed size for an image is 20MB',
        ]
    );
```